# Is there a way to serialise JSON value using avro-rs in Rust?

Tags: rust, avro

I would like to serialise a JSON value using [avro-rs](https://github.com/flavray/avro-rs). I can't seem to find a way to do this. To reproduce you can do the following:

1. Create a new project by running `cargo new example`
2. Update the `Cargo.toml` with the following dependencies:

```rust
[package]
name = "rust-example"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
serde_json = "1.0.52"
avro-rs = "0.10.0"
```

3. Update the `scr/main.rs` with:

```rust
use avro_rs::{Schema, Writer};
use serde_json::json;

fn main() {
    let raw_schema = r#"
        {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "action",
            "fields": [
                {"name": "id", "type": "string"}
            ]
        }
    "#;

    let schema = Schema::parse_str(raw_schema).unwrap();

    let mut writer = Writer::new(&schema, Vec::new());

    let action = json!({
        "id": "some id"
    });

    writer.append(action).unwrap(); // panics: ValidationError("value does not match schema")
}
```

4. Finally run `cargo run` to see the output.

Comment: Okay, will do that and update.

Comment: Updated the question so it should now contain a minimal reproducible example. Let me know if I need to do anything else to ensure the question is up to required standards.

Comment: Looks much better, thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `avro_rs`, but the documentation seems to list two different approaches, i.e. "the `avro` way" and "the `serde` way". It seems you're using both of them here? Could that possibly be the cause  of it not working? The methods are listed here: https://docs.rs/avro-rs/0.10.0/avro_rs/#writing-data

Answer (score 0):

You could try [avrow](https://crates.io/crates/avrow) crate. It has a `from_json` API: https://docs.rs/avrow/0.2.0/avrow/struct.Record.html#method.from_json on the `Record` type.

Check the [json example](https://github.com/creativcoder/avrow/blob/e79a4205e837bac8a92e1635650ad44600bd5a99/examples/from_json_to_struct.rs) in the repository.